# Joining streams Flink doesn't work with Kafka consumer

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink

I'm trying to join two streams, one from the data collection, one consumes from Kafka.

*code snippet*

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        KafkaSource<JsonNode> kafkaSource = ...
        
        final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        
        // Kafka messages : {"name": "John"} 
        final DataStream<JsonNode> dataStream1 = env.fromSource(kafkaSource, waterMark(), "Kafka").rebalance()
                .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(waterMark());
        
        final DataStream<String> dataStream2 = env.fromElements("John", "Zbe", "Abe")
                .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(waterMark());
        
        dataStream1
            .join(dataStream2)
            .where(new KeySelector<JsonNode, String>() {
    
                @Override
                public String getKey(JsonNode value) throws Exception {
                    return value.get("name").asText();
                }
            })
            .equalTo(new KeySelector<String, String>() {

                @Override
                public String getKey(String value) throws Exception {
                    return value;
                }
            })
            .window(SlidingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.minutes(50) /* size */, Time.minutes(10) /* slide */))
            .apply(new JoinFunction<JsonNode, String, String>() {
    
                @Override
                public String join(JsonNode first, String second) throws Exception {

                    return first+" "+second;
                }
            }).print();
            
            env.execute();
    }
```

*watermark*

```
private static <T>  WatermarkStrategy<T> waterMark() {
        return new WatermarkStrategy<T>() {

            @Override
            public WatermarkGenerator<T> createWatermarkGenerator(
                    org.apache.flink.api.common.eventtime.WatermarkGeneratorSupplier.Context context) {
                return new AscendingTimestampsWatermarks<>();
            }
            
            @Override
            public TimestampAssigner<T> createTimestampAssigner(TimestampAssignerSupplier.Context context) {
                return (event, timestamp) -> System.currentTimeMillis();
            }
            
        };
    }
```

After running snippet code, it doesn't have any merged data in the output. Am I going wrong somewhere?

*Apache flink version: 1.13.2*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably related to watermarking. Since you're not using event-time-based timestamps, try changing `SlidingEventTimeWindows` to `SlidingProcessingTimeWindows` and see if it then produces results.

The underlying problem is probably a lack of data. The `rebalance()` on the Kafka stream guarantees that idle partitions won't stall the watermarks unless all partitions are idle. But if this is an unbounded streaming job, unless you have some data that falls after the first window, the watermark won't advance far enough to trigger the first window.

Options:

1. Send some data with larger timestamps
2. Configure the Kafka source as a bounded stream by using the `.setBounded(...)` option on the KakfaSource builder
3. Stop the job using the `--drain` option ([docs](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/deployment/cli/#terminating-a-job))

The fact that dataStream2 is bounded is also a problem, but I'm not sure how much of one. At best this will prevent any windows after the first one from producing any results (since datastream joins are inner joins).

Comment: It's worked. But how I can use the `SlidingEventTimeWindows`?

Comment: See the edits to my answer